# Best SAX Parser Framework in java

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, saxparser

I have a requirement to parse xml files which are around 1 to 3 GB. If I am not wrong to parse such huge xml files sax parsing mechanism is used. Please suggest the best **SAX parser framework**

Comment: SAX isn't a framework. are you asking for the best SAX parser implementation?

Answer (score 0):

**javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser** is the parser I suggest

Answer (score 0):

As Sanjaya, I've also been using javax.xml.

For the task of parsing files in the gigabyte range that also have complex schemas, I've however used a custom StAX parser that implements XMLStreamReader ( http://woodstox.codehaus.org/javadoc/stax-api/1.0/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader.html ).
This allows for an event based, stateless parser.

Comment: Thanks Jesuli for your valuable suggestion